# ios app authentication with azure active directory

Tags: swift, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

[image]

we have download sample code from github https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-ios-swift-native-v2. now we have changed the microsoft app id/client id  in it. and we have this error in our app . which  I have shared in the screen shot . you could explain us that  it is because due to our url settings or something else . if this is due to our url settings could you please elaborate how we can set our url .
Regards Subhan Fazal.

Comment: Can you share the changes you made from the sample? The error message seems like a transient issue... have you tried again since that time?

Comment: it is working now i will comment back in a day or two if i got this problem again

Comment: the real problem is when i use the steps given in the heading of **(Optional) Configure a native client application**  in the following url it give me  error [link]https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-active-directory-authentication but i use this url [link]https://apps.dev.microsoft.com to register app it runs fine but this doesnot authenticate with directory

Comment: @Marc LaFleur - MSFT